# how to boot Ubuntu from windows 8

Tags: installation

i had installed windows 7(32 bit) and Ubuntu. It was working fine, but after that I installed Windows 8 (64 bit) instead of Windows 7. Now I'm unable to boot Ubuntu. 
Please help me to open my previous Ubuntu and how I'll get my data which were inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Desktop download page

> If you have a PC with the Windows 8 logo or UEFI firmware, choose the 64-bit download. [Read more ›](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Hope this answers your question.